# opsweekly -- Cannot get passed " I don't know what to do with this FQDN, please add it to config.php"

Tags: php, git

Cannot get passed "I don't know what to do with this FQDN, please add it to config.php" while setting it up. I have spent some time inside the config.php file but have gotten no where.

This is the git hub link for it: https://github.com/etsy/opsweekly

Looks pretty new and I have found very little documentation on how to set it up.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) options are at the bottom of config.php

```
$dev_fqdn = "/(\w+).vms.mycompany.com/";
// The prod FQDN is then subsituted in place of the above string.
$prod_fqdn = "mycompany.com";
```

Replace these parameters with your dev and production domain names and it should work.

If you still have problems, file an issue on their tracker:

https://github.com/etsy/opsweekly/issues